# why does VBA put 'range' instead of just range

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA to place a formula in a cell like so

```
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],CompanyUserEntries!B2:X" & URowCount & ",1,TRUE),"""")"
```

But Excel ends up turning it into this

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;CompanyUserEntries!'B2':'X12';1;TRUE);"")
```

the ' symbol around the range causes the formula not to work. Any idea how i can reference this range propperly without breaking my formula?

Comment: `CompanyUserEntries!B2:X12` should work for you

Comment: @Ian, imagine the row number for column X is a variable.

Comment: Even in vba when i put  B2:X12 , it still becomes 'B2':'X12' for some reason ;(

Comment: @teylyn oops got it. Didn't understand the question properly.

Comment: Could you share a sample file on a file sharing service? Saves time trying to repro the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix R1C1 and A1 notations in the same formula. Try using only R1C1 notation :

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],CompanyUserEntries!R2C2:R" & URowCount & "C24,1,TRUE),"""")"
```

Comment: @wouldbenerd Yes this is correct. If you modify the code like `ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,CompanyUserEntries!B2:X" & URowCount & ",1,TRUE),"""")"` it will work.

Comment: Thanks , I'm used to writing vba from scratch but i got lazy was modifying recorded macro. Was unfamiliar with this RC method until now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using RC?

`"R2C2:R" & URowCount & "C24"`

That should work for you.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],CompanyUserEntries!R2C2:R" & URowCount & "C24,1,TRUE),"""")"
```